# Finding how many filtered ports of a host that would be listed as “filtered” on Nmap

Tags: network, nmap, ports

I just started working on nmap and was confused by this question. I'm unsure if I understood it correctly, so I appreciate your help with this.

*Using Nmap, find how many ports are filtered in testphp.vulnweb.com are displayed as "filtered."*

From my understanding, it was asking me to find filtered ports that would be displayed as filtered. If i want to find how many filtered ports of a host that would be listed as “filtered”, would I use the -sA command for the firewall or is there a way to do that? I’ve tried -d2 but only found ALL filtered ports.

Please let me know if I'm overthinking it or the question should be interpreted differently. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Filtered ports can be differs according to your scan method. I think the purpose of the question is to understand this. so run it with all possible switches and compare the output to see which one is better to bypass firewall

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138179)

Comment: actually if read his question you will see my answer is what he need. he is been asked to perform this scan to find filtered ports. for me this means which nmap method or which combination of switches will bypass firewall and detect open ports. am i wrong?